# Prevent event to be registered multiple times JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using a library (javascript fullCalendar) that can be initialized with a lot of options/events.

The problem occur when I submit a form and because I need some params from one of the library event I put the submit event in the event. So I have:

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ..............................
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            $("#addEvent").submit(function (event) {

            //use date variable

            }
         });
    });
```

First time the submit is ok, but second time the submit trigger 2x, third time the submit is triggered 3x and so . How can I handle this problem? I was thinking to make a function but each time I call the function the submit event is registered and same problem occur.

Comment: try using `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` inside your function

Comment: You can also use .off() to unbind event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you not to bind the `submit` event handler in the `dayClick` event handler instead you can store the `date` in *cache* or a *variable* which can be used later.

```
var ddate;
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
      ddate = date; //Persist the date
     //OR, Persist the date in cache with element
     //$("#addEvent").data('date', date); 
  })
})


  //Event handler associate at global level
$("#addEvent").submit(function (event) {
    //use date variable
    var date = ddate;
   //var date = $("#addEvent").data('date')
});
```

As far as your current problem, You can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove previous event handler.

```
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $("#addEvent").off('submit').submit(function (event) {
           //use date variable
        });
     });
```

Comment: Why put the date on the element rather than just in a variable?

Comment: Why not to set a data attribute on the modal I will open? Why variable instead element?

Answer (score 0):

You can 'tag' the element when you attach the event the first time, then in the next calls you can exclude the re-attach of the event:

```
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
..............................
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
       $("#addEvent").not('.eventManaged').addClass('eventManaged').submit(function (event) {

        //use date variable

        }
     });
});
```

Hope it helps!